# Find the exact curve of this vector

Tags: calculus, vectors, curves

Suppose the curve $C$ is given by the vector function

**r**$(t)=(\sinh(t),\cosh(t),t)$

where $t\geq-1$. Find the exact curvature of $C$ at the point $(0,1,0)$.

My  idea isto find the length of **T**$'(t)$ and divide that by the length of **r**$'(t)$. So I started off by finding $|$**r**$'(t)|$ and i got:

**r**$'(t)=(\cosh(t),\sinh(t),1)$

$|$**r**$'(t)|$ = $\sqrt{2\sinh(t)^2+2}$

Now should I take **r**$'(t)$ and divide it by $|$**r**$'(t)|$, then take that whole value and divide it by $|$**r**$'(t)|$?

Comment: What is ${\bf T}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you compute the Expression $r''(t)=\frac{dr'(t)}{dt}$. Since it holds $\frac{ds}{dt}=|r'(t)|$ and $\frac{dr'(t)}{ds}=\kappa n$ for the arclength $s$ and the unit normal vector $n$, you arrive at $\kappa = |\frac{dr'(t)}{ds}| = |\frac{dr'(t)}{dt} \frac{dt}{ds}|=|\frac{dr'(t)}{|r'(t)|dt}|=\frac{|r''(t)|}{|r'(t)|}$. You get the curvature of the curve $\kappa$ as a function of $t$. Find the value $t$ which corresponds to the Point $C$ and you are done.

Comment: Oh so I just need to simply take $|$**r**$''(t)|$ divide that by $|$**r**$'(t)|$ and then I'll have $K$, meaning now all I would have to do is plug in $t=-1$, and I would have my answer correct?

Comment: Yes. You plug in $t=0$ since (sinh(0),cosh(0),0)=(0,1,0).

Comment: Oh yes I must also find the t value that gives that point, while making sure it is greater than -1, thank you I knew I was close!